# Optimizing query with LIMIT mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table, lets call it `mytable`, which holds huge amount of data that I need to query based on some column values of types `varchar` and `datetime` (none of these columns have indexing on them and I cannot use primary key for this query).

I need to fetch the data with pagination, for which I am using variables `varLimit` and `varOffset`. Now what I have noticed after much experimentation is that though `LIMIT varLimit` optimizes a query when result count is high, it severely reduces performance when it is greater than the result count. If the query returns 0 rows, with LIMIT 20 applied it takes 30 more seconds than it does with the LIMIT removed!

Here's my query

```
SELECT `data`
FROM mytable
WHERE (conditions...)
ORDER BY `heure` desc LIMIT varLimit OFFSET varOffset;
```

To optimize this, I have to first re-calculate `varLimit` to set it to the minimum value between result count and itself (`varLimit = 20` but if query returns 10 rows, it should set `varLimit = 10`. The final code becomes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO varCount
FROM mytable
WHERE (conditions...);

SELECT LEAST(varLimit, varCount - varOffset) INTO varLimit; -- Assume varOffset <= varCount 

SELECT `data`
FROM mytable
WHERE (conditions...)
ORDER BY `heure` desc LIMIT varLimit OFFSET varOffset;
```

Is there any way to do it in a single query, or a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: I see this as a substantial drawback of LIMIT clause if it underperforms where result set is smaller

Comment: I understand your question better, thanks to your comment. You'll need an index. But, help you figure out what index you need, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use variables in LIMIT and OFFSET clauses. They must be constants, so you must do this limit/offset computation either in application code or by creating a MySQL ["prepared statement"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) with string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for responding! No the queries are actually part of a stored proc, it's completely functional with the variable, I just need to improve it, like setting a minimum of count and varLimit in a single query, but then again it would become a subquery.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.21 if that helps..

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html: _"Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables."_